# Finalising WebPreferences in foswiki

Tags: twiki, preferences, foswiki

How can i finalise the preferences in foswiki so that no other user except the admin can override them.... thnx in advance for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the 'FINALPREFERENCES' setting on your Main.SitePreferences topic - see http://foswiki.org/System/DefaultPreferences#Protected_System_Settings

see the bottom of Main.SitePreferences for an example